Getting multiple tags from a specific parent to be stylized the quick way
I'm trying to get all bold texts from an anchor tags to have the same style.
I tried with :
a > h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,strong,b,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6{
  font-weight:var(--medium);
}

But the style is only applied on <h1>.
So I tried with :
a>h1,a>h2,a>h3...{ }

But then I realized that typing out :hover and :active would be tedious at it'll take a total of 28 times.
What is the quickest way to type out a > h1,h2,...,d5,d6 including both :hover and :active ?

Have a look at SASS / LESS (or nested CSS - caniuse)

a>h1,a>h2,a>h3...{  color: blue; &:hover {  color: red;}  } https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting

and usually you might want to use CSS classes. One class that does what it says.

CSS :is can help here.


<style>
  a> :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, strong, b, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6) {
    font-weight: var(--medium);
    color: red;
  }
  
  a:hover> :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, strong, b, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6) {
    font-weight: var(--medium);
    color: green;
  }
</style>
<a>
  <h2>h2</h2>
</a>




could probably just have ONE and put &:hover {  color: green;} nested inside the first right after thered;

Yes, I wasn't too sure what it was that was to be hovered - need OP to clarify.

If you are trying to avoid to repeat the target elements, you'll have to use JavaScript and not CSS.
With JavaScript, you can add an EventListener to the DOM content loading, and use a selector there for your {a > h1, a > h2, ...}.
It should look like this:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('a > h1, a > h2');

  targetElements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.color = 'red';
  });
});

And for :hover and :active, you should use the same eventListener and add some EventLister for mouseover, mouseout, mouseup and mousedown.
The completed JavaScript code should look like this. Of course, rearrange the const targetElements and the change of style you want to do for each actions:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('a > h1, a > h2');

  targetElements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.color = 'red';

    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      element.style.color = 'blue';
    });

    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      element.style.color = 'red';
    });

    element.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    });

    element.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        element.style.textDecoration = '';
    });
  });
});

Check it out here: demo

@Adam the link you give clearly states: " You cannot use var() for property names, selectors, or anything aside from property values,..."

You are both right, I made some changes to my quick and uncertain answer... That's my bad.

I would change should to could though

I think you can do this without JavaScript

This is too complex. I only want CSS, not JS
